# Puppet and Facter default system facts

Tags: linux, ubuntu, x86-64, ubuntu-12.04, puppet

I'm still quite new to puppet however I'm writing some deployments with it.

I came a across an issue where I couldn't get symlinks right because for some reason I was getting a mismatch between existing system folders  and puppet ${architecture} variable.

I need the following code to work as following:

On Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64 I sould get a link from `/usr/lib/libz.so` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so` However, I'm getting insted to `/usr/lib/amd64-linux-gnu/libz.so` which doesn't exist creating than a broken link.

```
file {"/usr/lib/libz.so":
    ensure => link,
    target => "/usr/lib/${architecture}-linux-gnu/libz.so",
}
```

Puppet uses Facter to get system facts, and running facter on my command line I get the following:

```
root@somehost:/root# facter
architecture => amd64
facterversion => 1.6.5
hardwareisa => x86_64
(....)
```

Running `lscpu` I get:

```
root@tsomehost:/root# lscpu 
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
(....)
```

My question is, where does Facter gets its facts from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Facter documentation now includes docs about [how core facts are resolved](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/1.6/core_facts.html).

- [architecture](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/1.6/core_facts.html#architecture) uses hardwaremodel, which calls `uname -m` and then on Debian converts `x86_64` to `amd64`
- [hardwareisa](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/1.6/core_facts.html#hardwareisa) calls `uname -p`

`$hardwaremodel` might be what you want here, however I think it will return x86_64 if you used a 64-bit kernel with a 32-bit userland, which probably isn't correct for your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

What is your version of Puppet and Facter?

Maybe you have an < 1.6.5 Facter version and thus have this bug: http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/11511

Try upgrading if you can.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it seems that is not the reason

root@myhost:~# facter --version
1.6.5

Comment: Reading more carefully the bug report, 1.6.5 may be affected as well. The patches that seem to correct the issue have been integrated in Facter 1.6.9. If you are able to upgrade to this version I'd be happy to know the result!

Comment: I think andrefsp's not affected by that for some reason.  Having $architecture resolve to amd64 is intended on Debian derivatives, while the bug is reporting that this _doesn't_ work for some.